# How to check if MySQL query is valid without executing it?

Tags: mysql, validation

I'm making a simple tool that will get a string of MySQL commands and run it (on several DB servers sequentially). I trust the users to be sensible, but mistakes happen, and I'm looking for a way to prevent basic typos:

Is there a way to validate, at runtime, (relatively simple) MySQL queries to see if they're syntactically correct?

I'm not looking for semantic correctness, e.g. table names or join applicability; just something like a spellcheck for SQL queries.

In other words,

```
SELECT * FROM x;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO x SET id=1,bar="foo";
```

would be marked valid, whereas any of those would not:

```
SELECT FROM x;
SECLET * RFOM x;
ISNETR INTO x SET id=1;
HJBGYGCRYTCY;
```

For `SELECT`s, I could bend `EXPLAIN` to my needs - run `EXPLAIN SELECT (...)` and watch for errors, but is there a way to check for other commands as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not without knowledge of the schema (for example, is 'x' a table?) and writing a SQL parser.  Your MySQL query tool should be able to do that kind of validation (intellisense if you like) but I know from first hand experience, most of the (free) MySQL tools are abysmal.

'Preparing' the query would do what you want, but is a runtime check, not a compile time check - you seem to be looking for a compile time/offline solution.

Comment: I was looking for a quick way of checking the queries before the script executes them. Writing a parser would be way overboard - if it breaks on the first server, it'll just exit with an error (supposedly the script users (system admins) are sane enough to know what they're doing).

Comment: +1 For prepare. That's the only way to do it to my knowledge.

Comment: It seems that MySQL can't run PREPARE on an empty db. And some syntactical errors are not shown up, for example two field with the same name.

Comment: Using phpMyAdmin, I copied some SQL into the query box. I changed the parameters to match my own schema, but needed to adjust the copied query by adding a `WHERE` clause to limit its effects. I didn't notice there was a `;` at the end of the copied query, so it executed on the entire table. Then I got an error message from my standalone `WHERE` clause. If there were a way to check the validity of all SQL statements before executing any of them, phpMyAdmin could have warned me of the mistake before executing anything. Or, perhaps phpMyAdmin could wrap them in a transaction to solve this issue!

Answer (score 20):

To verify a query i use the EXPLAIN command. You can take any SQL query and add EXPLAIN before it and execute.
If query is wrong, error will be returned.

Examples:

```
explain select * from users;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
```

And wrong query

```
explain select * from users2;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.users2' doesn't exist
```

P.S. Explain works for insert, update, delete too. Not only select

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Not sure why a non-answer is marked as the correct answer, and the correct answer is at the bottom.

Comment: `explain select * from users;` MySQL says `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'sakila.users' doesn't exist
` Now `select * from users;` gives `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'sakila.users' doesn't exist` So whats wrong?

Comment: I think the table 'sakila.users' doesn't exist :)

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your MySQL engine and settings, you could start a transaction, try the query, and then do a rollback.  Assuming dirty reads are off, that should work.

Comment: Oh wow, I just posted a comment on James Ogden's answer with this same idea. I think phpMyAdmin, and any other RDMS front-end that allows multiple queries should automatically enclose them in a transaction by default.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a temporary table to circumvent side effects of the query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE users SELECT * FROM users;
INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES('UniqueName');
DROP TABLE users;
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='UniqueName'; -- Should return 0 results
```

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily create a stored procedure with your code and unique name.
Then you can drop it immediately. Transactions can't rollback SP creation.
But be careful, because it just syntax validation, so it doesn't check if an object (in your query) exists or not.

Answer (score -1):

delete from employee where columnname='salary';